# What command to I need to bind to Drop the Briefcase?

Tags: team-fortress-2

A Steam Bug is preventing me from checking my own config file (for some reason my `config.cfg` gets overridden with nonsense when I close TF2) so I have to keep it on Read-Only, but that's not why I'm here today.

I would like to bind 'Drop the briefcase' to <kbd>T</kbd>, but there's no way I could try and find the line of code manually since 'Drop Briefcase' is unbound by default. Even on the Tf2 Wiki the command was described incorrectly or I have overlooked it. I've been searching the web for a good half hour.

What is the command line to bind "drop the briefcase"?

```
bind "t" "?????"
```

It's probably a really quick check for anyone who owns the game. For reference I am referring to the config file at this location:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Team Fortress 2\tf\cfg\config.cfg
```

Comment: I commented to keep the junk out of the main question

Comment: Your own research effort isn't junk.

Comment: *[Comments Cleaned Up]* - @Azul, thanks for the additional information, I have included it into your question proper. Even for 'quick' questions like this it's always helpful to show the effort you've put in - it means we're less likely to suggest the same solutions you already tried, plus it might show say something you thought was obvious but is actually the cause of where you got stuck. Remember, we're all here to try and help, but you gotta help us help you :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After going to the TF2 wiki and doing a quick search for useful commands, I was able to find that it is "dropitem." So a command would be `bind "t" dropitem` or whatever you want to do for the command.

https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/List_of_useful_console_commands is my source.

Comment: I have actually been on that page however I searched the page for "briefcase" not intelligence. No need to rub it in my face how easy that was though

Comment: @AzulShiva Sorry bout that, realized that that extra part was a bit rude. Posted it without thinking while I was walking somewhere.